# Correcting a plist with dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Plist is copyed to `documents directory` if it doesn't exist.

If it already exists, I want to use the "Name" key from `NSDictionary` in `bundleArray` to find the matching `NSDictionary` in `documentsArray`.

When the match is found, I want to check for changes in the strings and replace them if there is a change.

If a match is not found it means this dictionary must be added to documents plist.

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[self managePlist];
return YES;
}

- (void)managePlist {

NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Objects.plist"];
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Objects" ofType:@"plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];

} else {

    NSArray *bundleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
    NSMutableArray *documentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    BOOL updateDictionary = NO;
    for(int i=0;i<bundleArray.count;i++) {

        NSDictionary *bundleDict=[bundleArray objectAtIndex:i];

        BOOL matchInDocuments = NO;
        for(int ii=0;ii<documentArray.count;ii++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *documentDict = [documentArray objectAtIndex:ii]; 
            NSString *bundleObjectName = [bundleDict valueForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString *documentsObjectName = [documentDict valueForKey:@"Name"];
            NSRange range = [documentsObjectName rangeOfString:bundleObjectName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                matchInDocuments = YES;
            }
            if (matchInDocuments) {

                if ([bundleDict objectForKey:@"District"] != [documentDict objectForKey:@"District"]) {
                    [documentDict setObject:[bundleDict objectForKey:@"District"] forKey:@"District"];
                    updateDictionary=YES;
                }
            }

            else {
                [documentArray addObject:bundleDict];
                updateDictionary=YES;
            }
        }
    }
    if(updateDictionary){
        [documentArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }

}
```

}

If I run my app now I get this message: `'-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

How can I fix this?

When this is fixed, do you think my code will work?

If not, I would be happy for some suggestions on how to do this. I have struggled for a while and really need to publish the update with the corrections! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the `documentDict` is actually immutable. Even though you assign it to an `NSMutableDictionary`, this doesn't accurately describe the underlying data.

```
NSMutableDictionary *documentDict = [documentArray objectAtIndex:ii];
```

should be:

```
NSMutableDictionary *documentDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[documentArray objectAtIndex:ii]];
```

and wherever you edit the `documentDict`, add:

```
 [documentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:ii withObject:documentDict];
```

Comment: This doesn't update the property list as the dictionary is copied when made mutable - OP needs my solution.

Comment: The edit should resolve this without having to resort to mixing CoreFoundation with NextStep.

Comment: Thanks, a very simple solution that did the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

When you read a plist from file, an immutable dictionary/array **with immutable children** is created, so your

```
  NSMutableDictionary *documentDict = [documentArray objectAtIndex:ii];
```

line is erfectively a lie - you don't have a mutable dictionary. To create a mutable object from a plist, have a look at [CFPropertyListCreateWithData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html) and specify `kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves` as the mutability option.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final and working code using the answer from James Webster. Thanks to H2CO3 as well for contribution.

```
- (void)managePlist {
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Object.plist"];
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Object" ofType:@"plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
} 
else 
{
    NSArray *bundleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
    NSMutableArray *documentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    BOOL updateDictionary = NO;
    for(int i=0;i<bundleArray.count;i++) {
        NSDictionary *bundleDict=[bundleArray objectAtIndex:i];            

        for(int ii=0;ii<documentArray.count;ii++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *documentDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[documentArray objectAtIndex:ii]];
            NSString *bundleObjectName = [bundleDict valueForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString *documentsObjectName = [documentDict valueForKey:@"Name"];
            NSRange range = [documentsObjectName rangeOfString:bundleObjectName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                 NSString *districtString = [bundleDict objectForKey:@"District"];
                if ([documentDict objectForKey:@"District"] != districtString) {
                    [documentDict setObject:districtString forKey:@"District"];
                    [documentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:ii withObject:documentDict];
                    updateDictionary=YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(updateDictionary){
        [documentArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}
}
```